# Powershell how to check if friday is the last day of the month , returning True from a Function

Tags: powershell, function

I have tried to make a function in Powershell that produces a True if the last day of the month is friday.

```
function Get-LastFridayOfMonth([DateTime] $d) {
    $lastDay = new-object DateTime($d.Year, $d.Month,[DateTime]::DaysInMonth($d.Year, $d.Month))
    $diff = ([int] [DayOfWeek]::Friday) - ([int] $lastDay.DayOfWeek)
    if ($diff -gT 0) {
        return $lastDay.AddDays(- (7-$diff))
    } else {
        return $lastDay.AddDays($diff)
    }
}
$testdate = Get-LastFridayOfMonth (Get-Date)
```

But how to check if that friday is the last day of the month ?

Comment: Add one day and see if the month changes :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Theo's answer reframes your question and gives a nice all-in-one solution, but to address your specific question:

> "*how to check if [a date] is the last day of the month ?*"

you can just add one day to the date and see if the month changes. If it *does* change then the original date must be the last one in the month…

```
$testdate = [datetime] "2023-01-31"
$isLastDayOfMonth = $testdate.AddDays(1).Month -ne $testdate.Month
$isLastDayOfMonth
# True

$testdate = [datetime] "2023-01-30"
$isLastDayOfMonth = $testdate.AddDays(1).Month -ne $testdate.Month
$isLastDayOfMonth
# False

$testdate = Get-LastFridayOfMonth (Get-Date)
$isLastDayOfMonth = $testdate.AddDays(1).Month -ne $testdate.Month
$isLastDayOfMonth
# depends on if the month ends on a friday
```

Comment: @mklement0 - As it stands, ```Get-LastFridayOfMonth``` returns literally the last Friday in the month of the given input date. E.g. ```Get-LastFridayOfMonth ([datetime] "2023-02-01")``` returns ```(Friday) 24 February 2023 00:00:00``` - the OP is asking if this date is the last in the month. It's working backwards a bit for sure and @theo's answer solves their intent better - I'm probably just being a bit pedantic by answering the question they asked rather than the one they meant :-)...

Comment: I think it's always worth  at least _also_ addressing the question as asked, and good point that you can solve the problem by _building on_ the function as written, which I didn't even consider. I was focused on _rewriting_ the function, given that it is most of the way there (naming aside). But I guess Theo's answer has that covered.

Answer (score 1):

I would change that function to just return the last days weekday so after calling it you can decide what weekday you get for the given date.

```
function Get-LastWeekDayOfMonth {
    param (
        [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date)
    )
    # .AddDays(-$Date.Day+1) sets the given date to the 1st of that month
    $Date.AddDays(-$Date.Day+1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek
}

switch (Get-LastWeekDayOfMonth) {
    'Friday' { "It's a Friday !" }
    default  { $_ }
}
```

Using the current date (February 2023) it would yield `Tuesday`

If you specify for instance March 2023

```
$d = Get-Date -Year 2023 -Month 3 -Day 1
switch (Get-LastWeekDayOfMonth -Date $d) {
    'Friday' { "It's a Friday !" }
    default  { $_ }
}
```

The outcome will be `It's a Friday !`

---

If however you want a function to simply return $true or $false when the month end in a Friday or not, do this instead:

```
function Test-LastDayOfMonthIsFriday {
    param (
        [datetime]$Date = (Get-Date)
    )
    # .AddDays(-$Date.Day+1) sets the given date to the 1st of that month
    $Date.AddDays(-$Date.Day+1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday'
}

Test-LastDayOfMonthIsFriday                                              # --> $false
Test-LastDayOfMonthIsFriday -Date (Get-Date -Year 2023 -Month 3 -Day 1)  # --> $true
```

Special thanks to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the `$Date.AddDays(-$Date.Day+1)` part which always sets the date to the first day of that month

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out, @Theo. Note that the body of `Test-LastDayOfWeekIsFriday` is missing `-eq 'Friday'` in order to return a `[bool]`

Comment: I might be being daft, but shouldn’t it be ```LastDayOfMonth``` instead if ```LastDayOfWeek```?